# How to download data from GES DISC using wget for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-prompt, wget

I  want to download all the `.nc4` files under this link https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/GLDAS/GLDAS_NOAH025_M.2.1/ by using wget command as stated in https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/information/howto/5761bc6a5ad5a18811681bae?keywords=wget

I downloaded wget Version 1.19.4 from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to enter username and password as described in https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/information/howto/5761bc6a5ad5a18811681bae?keywords=wget

Also, I did all the instructions step by step at this link https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/data-access When I enter `NUL > .urs_cookies`, it says Access is denied. But creates `.urs_cookies` file inside my directory.

Another way to download the data is to use Mirador https://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov/. After I add the data to my cart, it gives some instructions to download these files. However, I got stuck on the first step and could not save the URLs to my workstation. I guess I should download the .txt file as myfile.dat.

wget:

1. Save the list of URLs in one of the above links to your local workstation as myfile.dat

If you haven't done so already, follow these instructions to register with Earthdata Login system and authorize the access to GES DISC data

Create a `~/.netrc` file pointing to urs.earthdata.nasa.gov and an empty `~/.urs_cookies` file

On your command line, using wget 1.18 ( or higher ): `wget --content-disposition --load-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --save-cookies ~/.urs_cookies --auth-no-challenge=on --keep-session-cookies -i myfile.dat`

Could someone please help me to download these files? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem, but using the [chrono chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn?hl=fr) I can retrieve all the url.
Simply open the Earthdata login page in an other tab (because the tool need your id and pwd to download *.nc files), copy all the url and the plugin add a new task with all url.

Answer (score 1):

I successfully downloaded GES DISC data using wget and windows 10.
I needed data from 2018/04/01 to 2020/03/31. My procedure is:

1. Subset data according to date and bounding box, we can create a subset from this link, https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/OMNO2_003/summary.
   [There's a subset/get data button on the right side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP6KH.png)
2. In the subsetting dialogue box, select download method, date range, region, variables, and file format. Make sure to choose a format you are looking to download. In my case, it was NetCDF for Level-3 OMI data. After entering all parameters, click on get data.
3. This will create a list of links to satellite data along with a readme file and a user guide. After the download is ready click on the download links list. This will download a .txt file. Open this file in Notepad++ where you will see that the link for each satellite image is in a single line. Remove the lines that do not point to the satellite image and save it. (this was the first two lines in my case).
4. Go to https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/data-access#windows_wget, under "wget for Windows". Follow steps 1,2,3 and go to 4b (second command). Give your username after 'user='. In url.txt, give your file name in place of url. Do make sure that you keep your url.txt file and cookie file are in same folder. In your command prompt, enter the command. The files will start downloading in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /l %x in (1,1,10000) do wget -c --http-user=xxx  --http-passwd=xxx --load-cookies D:\wget_example\cookies.txt --save-cookies D:\wget_example\cookies.txt --no-check-certificate --auth-no-challenge=on --keep-session-cookies --content-disposition -i D:\wget_example\download.txt
```